# Error with symfony property acces in composer install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install depencies on my project, but I keep getting this error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for symfony/property-access v4.1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/property-access[v4.1.4].
>       - don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.15|don't install symfony/property-access v4.1.4
>       - Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.4.15 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.15].

My **composer.json**:

```
{
  "license": "proprietary",
  "type": "project",
    "classmap": [
      "app/AppKernel.php",
      "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
      "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "ext-pdo_pgsql": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.2.7",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "^7.0",
    "elao/web-profiler-extra-bundle": "^2.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.8",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "jms/job-queue-bundle": "^1.4",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.4",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/property-access": "^4.1",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "symfony/templating": "^3.0",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^3.3",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://repo.fury.io/8wbRFwcPzdATcTofLeQs/digitalascetic/"
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",` conflicts with `"symfony/property-access": "^4.1",`. Chances are you need all your Symfony dependencies to be of the same major version.

Comment: i tried with  symfony/property-access:3.4 got the same error

Comment: How did you install it and was the error message the same? `composer require symfony/property-access:^3.4`?